# Having TLS/SSL issues when trying to send a GET request

Tags: c#, webclient

I built an HTTP server on a board. Now, using c# I'm trying to send get requests to him (inside the local network), but I keep getting an error:

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

I'm using this code inside a button:

```
private async void btn_frd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sURL;
            sURL = "https://10.68.0.150/forward";
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(sURL);
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


        }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: already tried it... it's no good. this is the error I get: " Unable to connect to the remote server"

Comment: well, that's another problem then. But the answer to your question is removing the https since you didn't set up SSL. The error you described now, means that your HTTP server is offline or not working

Comment: no. I can access it using my browser easily.

Comment: This can happen if you use an unsupported .NET version and the server requires TLS1.2.  TLS 1.2 was added in .NET 4.5.2, the earliest supported version. If you use an older .NET version, you'll have to upgrade. Banks and airlines have been dropping support for anything less than TLS1.2 for over a year now

Comment: @NullDev when someone says "I have a problem with security", the answer is **never** to turn off security. And the message does **not** mean that the server is offline or not working. That would result in a timeout or a 500 error. That is a very, very, very specific message that says the SSL connection failed because the server doesn't trust the client

Comment: @user107761 what is your .NET version? Does the server require TSL1.2?

Comment: I have .NET version 4.6.1

Comment: You are using HTTPS, but the server is presumably using a self signed certificate. Your client knows this, and is not happy with sending requests to a server with a 'dodgy' certificate. There is a way to bypass the check and say "Just trust the certificate at this location", but as @PanagiotisKanavos says, the solution to a security problem is not to remove the security.

Comment: @plusheen this is my server, and all access is local, so I'm okay with bypass it. how can I do it?

Comment: @user107761You can bypass the certificate validation using `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate
            {
                return true;
            });` , however I cannot stress enough to not use this in production code. Ever. This opens up your application to a whole host of severe security issues.